# how to remove any multiple seleted items from drop down list using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to remove any multiple seleted items from drop down list using javascript.

```
function removeOptions(selectbox) {
    var city = selectbox;
    var i;
    for (i = city.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (selectbox.options[i].selected)
            selectbox.pop(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: post more code...or a snippet it would be a great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var select=document.getElementById(id name);

   var i;
    for(i=select.options.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
    if(select.options[i].selected)
    selectbox.remove(i);
    }
```

Try this code. I didn't test it.I  hope it works for you.

Comment: hello arjun , can you please tell me what is your option value.

Comment: hello,if in your html code you have something like this <option>value="A">A</option> then you can pass "A" in "your option value".

Comment: but i need to take that dynamically according to user selection.

Comment: then you can remove if loop and just write select.remove(i); in for loop.Try this .I hope it works

Comment: yes i do the same but it remove ALL  the option look at herefunction removeOptions()
    {
     //var city = selectbox; 
     //alert(city);
     var select=document.getElementById('city_name');
      for (var  i=0;i<select.length; i++) {
             select.remove(i);
      }
     }

Comment: in this it remove 0 index and 2 index when i am select any thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `<select>` element, this code should work:

```
var list = document.querySelector("select")
list.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    list.removeChild(e.target.selectedOptions[0])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is correct about what you are asking, I think you want

```
selectbox.removeChild(selectbox[i]);
```

Note that the variable `city` isn't needed since you can just use `selectbox` in its place.